Microcontroller that can do 10 UART?
I am currently working on a project that would require a total of 10 UART (rx and tx pins) to run 10 PZEM-004Ts for different electrical lines. I am thinking of using an atmega 2560 because it has plenty of hardware UART, and have the remaining as software UART. The problem is I do not know if the atmega 2560 could handle all the 10 UARTs nor do I think that the project is possible to make. I want to ask if anyone knows a better solution to execute the project?
How could I connect or use a microcontroller with 10 UARTS?

Impossible to answer. You need to give more details. Amount of data on RX and TX, Baud rates, necessary amount of data processing...

start with one PZEM-004T and test ... if successful then add another ... continue until all 10 are connected

A better solution is to use an MCU with 10 UARTs. Or if you don't need all 10 simultaneously, you can multiplex one UART to multiple devices if possible.

SPI or I2C to UART 'adapter' ICs exist. You could hook up a number of these to your MCU and end up with many more than 10 UARTs.

Got a datasheet...
"The library of PZEM-004t V30 works on hardware serial as well as software serial."
Looking at the source code...
The microcontroller sends a command to the device, which replies with measurement data.
Therefore, it should be possible to use one serial port to transmit commands, and a digital 1:N decoder to direct the command to the desired device's RXD pin.
Since all the devices have open collector TXD outputs, all TXDs can be wired together to the mcu's RXD, with a pullup resistor. If capacitance is a problem for high baud rates, or of the device transmits when not asked to do so, then a N:1 digital multiplexer can also be used.
With this design you need one UART, N output pins as select signal for the mux/decoder, plus TXD and RXD, for 2^N devices.
74HC4067, a 1:16 analog mux, would be well suited.

Now to answer your question: it would probably work because no matter how many pins you use, it's only going to talk to one device at a time. So the number of SoftwareSerial instances is irrelevant, since no multitasking is involved.
However, SoftwareSerial bit bangs the serial protocol, which means it's going to have to kill interrupts while doing so, which means it's going to suck a lot if you have any kind of precise interrupt requirements in your design. Since it's a mains current/power sensor, if you have an interrupt for zero crossing detection for example, it's not going to work with software serial.

Another solution would be to use something like an ESP32, which has a very useful pin mux. It can put the UART TXD and RXD on any pin you want, and it can be reconfigured at any time. Thus it can do the same thing as the separate mux chip I mentioned above, but it will use more pins. All you need to do is, for each sensor, configure the UART to use the corresponding pins, send command, read result, and then switch to the next sensor.

Good solution. Another option is to use two 74HC138 digital mux, where the MCU Tx feeds pin /2GA. This would hold the unselected Tx outputs active high for better noise immunity.

I would upgrade to a micro that has USB host (R.pi, say), and use a USB hub to multiple USB-to-serial adapters. This solves a number of interface and mechanical problems, and you get a much more capable platform for your trouble.
Otherwise, even if you have a fistfull of serial ports, you still need to have I/O translation to RS232 (aka 'TTL to Serial') which costs nearly the same as a USB serial.

This answer has two problems. First of all, you can't connect an arbitrarily high amount of USB to serial adapters to a micro or even Raspberry Pi. Each USB serial adapter takes at least 3 endpoints, 10 devices totaling at least 33 endpoints. And you need a hub to connect them. Each hub needs an endpoint for itself, and each downstream port also requires one endpoint. Assuming 10-port hubs are logically possible, it takes 11 endpoints. Requires already 40+ enpoints and some Rpi models support only 32. And these sensors are not RS-232 but logic level UART. A single muxed UART will do.
